# AsyncTask with facebook and twitter4j

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, android-asynctask, twitter4j

I have two images buttons and I'd like to share/tweet when I press it, but I was doing all the code in activity, so one day wasn't working anymore I don't know why :/ It was throwing a exception NetworkOnMainThreadException and it was in time to do all with AsyncTask. Since then I have been looking for a while and all solutions that I tested about this don't work... So I'd like you help me with this problem :D

```
class TweetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                AccessToken accessToken = loadAccessToken();
                if (accessToken == null) {
                    twitterL = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
                    twitterL.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
                    RequestToken requestToken = twitterL
                            .getOAuthRequestToken(CALLBACKURL);
                    String url = requestToken.getAuthenticationURL();
                    Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                    startActivity(it);
                    saveRequestData(requestToken.getToken(),
                            requestToken.getTokenSecret());
                } else {
                    twitterL.setOAuthAccessToken(accessToken);
                    if (loadAccessToken() != null) {
                        String tweet = "I'm listening ";
                        twitterL.updateStatus(tweet);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                showToast(e.getMessage());
            }

            return "1";
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String tweet) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException + google = solution

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException means you are making a network call on the main thread. put it in an asynctask, and voilà. Or, give more information about your issue. (code, stacktrace, stuff)

Comment: edit : deleted for being too sarcastic, sorry

Comment: So, I edited my question. This code I was trying to use on doInBackground() but it didn't work. facebook code didn't work too...

Comment: can you post the part of the code where you call the asynctask ? as well as the complete stacktrace ?

Comment: Code is above. This is the exception: 09-27 16:33:28.849: E/AndroidRuntime(317): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Android Honeycomb, any network activity performed on the UI thread/Main Activity thread will throw the NetworkOnMainThreadException

It has always been advised to perform long running method calls in a seperate AsyncTask rather than the UI thread. A method that fetches data from the internet is one example of a long running method. Please read more about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and implement it in your code to avoid this exception from being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

What you **could** do, is add this before your network calls:

```
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

And it will allow it on the main thread.
But only do this for extremely simple network calls. And I mean really simple.

As zeiger said, you should definitely learn about [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and use it in this situation.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. One never knows exactly how long a network call will actually take. AsyncTask is always a better approach, no matter how "simple" your network call is.

Comment: Could you post the code for your AsyncTask here? Its not possible for AsyncTask to throw the NetworkOnMainThreadException